# Add Trailing Ellipsis To Breadcrumb Depending On Device Width

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my user interface I have a breadcrumb of which shows on the top bar. Upon the device width being below a defined width, it'll drop below the top bar and be it's own bar, however what I do not know how to do is add a trailing ellipsis upon the breadcrumb length being larger than the device width.

**Example Breadcrumb:**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>>></li>
        <li>User</li>
        <li>>></li>
        <li>Inbox</li>
        <li>>></li>
        <li>Mail_ID</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

***Note:*** `>>` represents a FontAwesome icon in an `i` tag

Upon the breadcrumb being larger than the device width, the best I can describe what I would like to happen is demonstrated below:

- Home >> User >> Inbox >> Mail_ID
- ... User >> Inbox >> Mail_ID
- ... Inbox >> Mail_ID
- ... Mail_ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still a partial code but might help you.

#### Idea

- On load, call a function that checks for with of `ul` and its parent container.
- If `ul` has greater width, hide first 2 visible `li`. Also add an `li` for ellipsis and make it hidden initially and make it visible only if any of other divs are hidden.
- Repeat this process recursively and you will get what you are looking for.

**Sample**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".content").resizable();

  $(".content").on("resize", function() {
    var ul = $(this).find('ul');
    if (ul.width() > $(this).width()) {
      var lis = ul.find('li:not(.hide):not(.ellipsis)');
      for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        $(lis[i]).addClass("hide");
      }
      if ($(".ellipsis").not(":visible"))
        $(".ellipsis").removeClass("hide")
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.content {
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
}

.content ul {
  padding: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.content ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hide {
  display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="content">

  <ul>
    <li class="hide ellipsis">...</li>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>>></li>
    <li>User</li>
    <li>>></li>
    <li>Inbox</li>
    <li>>></li>
    <li>Mail_ID</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you very much. I just need to add a trailing ellipsis to the last `li` if it is the only one there and cannot fit on, otherwise an empty breadcrumb wouldn't be so useful!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the CSS-only ellipsis, but I don't know if it also works with `<ul><li>`. For sure it works with simple strings:

Use this HTML:

```
<ul class="ellipsis">
```

And this CSS:

```
ul.ellipsis
{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Will `overflow: hidden` not hide text to the right side?

Comment: AH, sure. He wants to cap on the beginning while I show how to hide on the end. Those are two completely different things.